# Python write to file - New line

Tags: python, file, newline

I am trying to write python code where I write to a fileand for each `f.write`. I want to make it write to a new line. I thought `\n` would do it. But right now everything is being written to one line. What am I doing wrong ?

Code (**localtime**, **sum** and **value** are variables)

```
f = open('/var/www/html/index.html','w')
f.write("<font size='35px'>"+sum+"</font>")
f.write('\n'+localtime)
f.write('\n Sist oppdatert '+value)
f.close()
```

Comment: Are you talking about a new line in the file or an actual new line break in the HTML document?

Comment: Tip: Please provide minimal working examples (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time you ask a question on SO.

Comment: There is a newline `\n` being correctly appended. What's going wrong for you?

Comment: In the HTML document. So when I view it from the browser it will give me a new line.

Comment: And please use a different variable name other than `sum` - it's a built in function.

Comment: HTML newline is `<br />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use line breaks `<br/>` for html line breaks:

```
f = open('/var/www/html/index.html','w')
f.write("<font size='35px'>"+sum+"</font>")
f.write('<br/>'+localtime)
f.write('<br/> Sist oppdatert '+value)
f.close()
```